# How to check if selected cell got reselected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell, heightforrowatindexpath

I have a custom `UITableViewCell`, and I it expands on selection. What I want to do is make the cells height go back to normal (44), if the cell that was selected was reselected. Here is my code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.selectedCell] && ![[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] isEqual:indexPath]) {
        return 100;
    }
    return 44;
}
```

The code works fine, but it seems to be ignoring the 2nd term in the if statement. Apparently I'm doing it wrong. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you followed the approach suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337041/disable-prepareforreuse-for-selected-cell/28338628#28338628

Comment: That is talking about `prepareForReuse`, I don't get what that has to do with anything?

Comment: Just trying to help. My suggestion is to use object models to control behaviors, not cell index paths and comparisons to selected cells. That is a recipe for ongoing frustration. If you had a model that was getting marked as selected when user selected the cell, then when they selected it again, you would only need to look at the model to know that, and you could respond accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store that particular index path in array to indicate that it is expanded Lets say you had selected 5 row that store that row number in an array, and reload that row after selecting it

Here is small code snippet that can help you to achieve this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if([_arrExpandedRows containsObject:indexPath.row]){
     [_arrExpandedRows removeObject:indexPath.row];
    }else{
     // [_arrExpandedRows removeAllObjects]; // IF you only want to make it work for single row
      [_arrExpandedRows addObject:indexPath.row];
    }
[tableView reloadData];
}
```

And in your `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

```
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([_arrExpandedRows containsObject:indexPath.row]){ 
    {
        return 100;
    }
    return 44;
}
```

So what will it do if your array contains object of expanded row it will make reduce its row height and back to 44 and if not it will make it back to 100.

And above code will also work for multiple rows to expand and collapse at same time.

Comment: I don't wanna have the capability of multiple selection

Comment: Also, you shouldn't have `indexPath.row`, it should only be `indexPath`

Comment: Yes you also can store indexPth.row , it depends on you what you want to compare but this logic will work perfect for multiple row expand collapse. If you only want to have one row to work you can remove all object befor adding last object to array. See my Updated ans.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you compare cell with indexPath.

```
[indexPath isEqual:self.selectedCell]
```

If you just want expand selected cell.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] isEqual:indexPath]) 
    {
        return 100;
    }
    return 44;
}
```

UITableViewDelegate has deselect method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You need reload cell in this delegate

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: If a cell is selected, and that same cell gets reselected, I want to return 44. For example: If I select cell #6 it should expand to 100. Now if I **reselect** cell #6, I want it to go back to the height of 44, not 100.

Comment: you can store indexPath (before call reloadRowsatIndexPaths) to selected cell, and compare it in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:  to determine hight of cell. And you should reload old selected indexPath and new selected index path i.e. @[oldIndexPath<if != nil>, newIndexPath].

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView* tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* selectedIndexPaths;

@end
<...>
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_ID];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (int)indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CGFloat height = 44.0;
   if ([_selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])
   {
       height = 100;
    }

   return height;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{//store or remove selected indexPaths
    if ([_selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [_selectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
    }
   else
   {
        [_selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: 1 - At `heightForRow...`, in the if statement, there is no such thing as `indexOfObject`.    2 - At `didSelectRow...` in the if statement, there is no `containtsObject`

Comment: _selectedIndexPaths is instance of NSMutableArray, it contains these methods. (http://goo.gl/YqAWWG -- indexOfObject:),  (http://goo.gl/32eoJf -- containObject:).

Comment: I'll edit my answer to use same method.  [_selectedIndexPaths indexOfObject:indexPath] != NSNotFound is equal to [_selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]

Comment: sorry. my bad. I was using it as an NSIndexPath

Comment: I've posted my project to guthub, you can exam it https://github.com/K-Be/CellsExpand . I think you've forgotten to initialize selectedIndexPaths.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70379/discussion-between-andrew-romanov-and-mike-rally).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is unselect cell when tap on a selected cell.

Store selectedIndexPath and compare in delegate

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
    {
         [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:1];
    }
    else
    {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    }          
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```